# Methods in AppDelegate to manage app life cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I have a problem when using methods in AppDelegate to manage my own app. I want my file encrypted when app de-active and decrypted when app active, and here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.

    // encrypt file
    NSString *_path = path_to_file;
    if ([PVIFileHelper isfileExisting:_path] && ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kFileEncrypted]) {
        To_do_Encrypted_file;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kFileEncrypted];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    // decrypt data
    NSString *_path = path_to_file;
    if ([PVIFileHelper isfileExisting:_path] && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kFileEncrypted]) {
        To_do_Decrypted_file;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:kFileEncrypted];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

}
```

`kFileEncrypted` is a key which kept en-decrypted file state.
But when app crashed (for any other reason), my file was confused en-decrypted state. `kFileEncrypted` value is YES when app decrypted and reverse.
What is my mistake?

Comment: Your mistake is trying to encrypt data yourself rather than using the operating system capabilities; As you have found, it is possible for your app to terminate unexpectedly, leaving your file unencrypted.  You cannot guarantee that some code will execute before your app terminates; it may crash, the device may be force rebooted, the battery may go flat.  If `NSFileProtectionComplete` is not sufficient then you should consider decrypting the file into RAM and leaving the file always encrypted on the file system

Comment: Nice idea, thank @Paulw11